# SVN Authentication / Logging without user

Tags: svn, apache2

Currently i've setup a SVN server with CollabNet Edge which uses SSL access and LDAP authentication which works. But one thing is what i don't understand...

The first is the line which i can't understand. Why do i get a entry in the log file which does not contain the username. All other entries are ok. I access the repository via svn list https://example.com/svn/repositoryName

```
www.xx.yy.zz - - [04/Oct/2012:16:49:18 +0200] "OPTIONS /svn/repositoryName HTTP/1.1" 401 401
www.xx.yy.zz - username [04/Oct/2012:16:49:18 +0200] "OPTIONS /svn/repositoryName HTTP/1.1" 200 194
www.xx.yy.zz - username [04/Oct/2012:16:49:18 +0200] "OPTIONS /svn/repositoryName HTTP/1.1" 200 194
www.xx.yy.zz - username [04/Oct/2012:16:49:18 +0200] "PROPFIND /svn/repositoryName/!svn/rvr/12345 HTTP/1.1" 207 1303
www.xx.yy.zz - username [04/Oct/2012:16:49:18 +0200] "PROPFIND /svn/repositoryName/!svn/rvr/12345 HTTP/1.1" 207 4748
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVN sends the credentials only if needed, so it will always try first to retrieve the data without sending login data. As your server answers HTTP-Code 401 (Unauthorized), svnclient will add the credentials in a second attempt.

Comment: Hi, I'm also getting the same error in apache access log `www.xx.yy.zz - - [04/Oct/2012:16:49:18 +0200] "OPTIONS /svn/repositoryName HTTP/1.1" 401 401`
After this msg, continuously 3 times, the operation is aborted saying error.
FYI, I’m using SVN with Apachec2.2 – NTLM
I am not able to proceed with this. Let me know how to handle this.

Comment: You may have the wrong credentials(username/pw combination)? If you wont have the correct permission server would log a 403